# Debug doesn't work after clicking Debug in UI autotests (java, maven)

Tags: java, maven, debugging, junit, automated-tests

I had autotests java, maven.
After clicking Debug, I see "No tests were found"

Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:33785', transport: 'socket'
Apr 19, 2022 2:30:31 PM org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherConfigurationParameters fromClasspathResource
INFO: Loading JUnit Platform configuration parameters from classpath resource [file:/home/name/IdeaProjects/project/target/classes/junit-platform.properties].
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:33785', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 0

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jdjgu.png)

If click Run tests - tests pass, everything is fine.
I tried all things that can find - reinstall project, update dependencies, change jdk version, set project in other folder, add addition libraries.

I see that something wrong with classpath but I can't find

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

Setting -> find async -> deactivate checkbox -> save changes

[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8hh6.png)